# How to create a 802.11ac access point with NetworkManager?

Tags: wireless-access-point, networkmanager, 802.11ac

I'm creating a WiFi access point on the 5GHz band with the NetworkManager on Ubuntu 20.04. My WiFi chipset is an Intel AX200. I use the following command to create the acces point:

`sudo nmcli dev wifi hotspot ifname wlp4s0 ssid TestAccesPoint password test1234 band a channel 149`

This works fine so far, but every client only connects in the 802.11n mode, which results in an unsatisfactory bit rate. How can I teach the NetworkManager to establish a 802.11ac connection? As far as I know, my WiFi adapter should be capable of this.

Comment: Can you check your wireless router another way and ensure it is operating on AC?  In Ubuntu, can you use the GUI Network Setup to establish the connection (Settings, Network).  I have 2 computers here: 1 AC, 1 N and they choose correctly.

Comment: It's weird that there isn't a way to specify important parameters like security mode and channel width. It looks to me like nmcli's syntax is stuck in 2004 and doesn't have options for modern Wi-Fi networks.

Comment: @John As a WiFi client my computer connects to other networks correctly in AC or AX mode. My devices I use to connect to the computer when I set it up as an access point can also connect to other WiFi networks in AC mode. So the hardware shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: If nothing were wrong, then it would connect fine. Make sure the Workstation Wireless driver is up to date, make sure the settings are correct (I suggested the alternate GUI Network Manager), and check Firmware revision on the router for compatibility with your workstation card.  (this is not really hardware).

Comment: I took care of all that of course. The best NetworkManager has to offer is 802.11n with 144MBit/s connection speed. It actually doesn't matter at all what hardware I use. NetworkManger just seems to be stuck in the past as Spiff said.

Comment: It's 2023 now, but I saw no improvement yet.